# Can I customize a BarChart for this purpose?

Tags: apache-flex, flex-charting

I'm kind of new to using charts in Flex, so you'll have to forgive me if I'm asking something for which there's an obvious answer.

I have a need to create a BarChart which acts more like a List component, albeit it should still be a chart. I need items to look somewhat like this:

```
<s:HGroup width="100%">
    <s:Button id="labelDisplay" label="Item Name"/>
    <s:BARCHARTGRAPHTHING width="100%"/>
    <s:Label text="{data.count}"/>
</s:HGroup>
```

Thus, an item should look kind of like this:

[image]

Is there a way to customize the MX BarChart component to allow me to provide a custom item renderer for the part that renders the label for the row? Is there also a way for me to add a total column next to the bar on the right?

[image]

Additionally, I need to be able to allow my chart to handle a lot of different rows of data. Can I make it act more like a list and add a scroller, keeping the ticks at the bottom above all bars?

Comment: try extending the barchart component

Comment: Looks like what you want is a DataGroup, with a bit of customization.

Comment: So I'll need a SkinnableDataGroup and a way to draw the lines on the bottom? The problem is going to be drawing the actual bars, as I can't just draw percent-based, I have to somehow know what my biggest number is and know how the ticks are drawn. This is going to be hard.